# Should I replant a watermelon that almost died when planted in the ground?

Tags: transplanting, repotting, watermelon

I started a watermelon in the ground as a small plant. It basically died in the ground, so I took it out. The roots had not really taken.

After a few weeks, however, I repotted it in a container just to see if it would come back.  So it has and know I am wondering can I replant in the ground without it taking another hit?  Thoughts?

I need to replant it as soon as possible!

Comment: why do you think it failed to thrive in the ground?

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: I will take one in the morning.

Answer (score 3):

*Cucurbitaceae*, which includes watermelons, hate any damage to their roots - even somebody just walking too close to them. If "in the ground as a small plant" means you planted a seedling, my guess is you damaged the roots when transplanting it.

I have planted seedlings from nurseries, but seed wherever you want them to grow is the safer bet if you can provide them with the needed conditions.

**EDIT**: If you transplant it, you are likely going to stunt its growth again. Grow it in the pot and call it a year. Feed it high nitrogen until it gets large enough and then switch to low nitrogen.

Comment: So my question....it is currently in a pot...do i re transplant it back to the ground?

Comment: @Hillary My vote is for no.